# Loading image as Sprite in Andengine

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

I have searched all the forums but I am unable get any working code.
I want to load an image as sprite from SD Card in and engine.
Can any one provide me a code? I am using

```
    File imageFile = new File("/path/to/image");
    BitmapTextureAtlas texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(width , height , TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
    ITextureSource fileTextureSource = new FileTextureSource(imageFile);
    TextureRegion textureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(texture,fileTextureSource ,0,0);
```

but

```
ITextureSource fileTextureSource = new FileTextureSource(imageFile);
```

is giving me error that ITextureSource cannot be resolved to a type.
I am using AndEngine GLES1. Please help me and give me a way to make sprite from SD Card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried the code, but I put it in Eclipse and tried fixing it so that it compiles. This is the result:

```
File imageFile = new File("/path/to/image");
BitmapTextureAtlas texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(width , height , TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource fileTextureSource = new FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource(imageFile);
TextureRegion textureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(texture,fileTextureSource ,0,0, true);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. :) We just missed to load the texture though :)

Comment: Hello JohnEye and Jawad Amjad: I too had the same problem. Not yet solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501897/setting-screen-sprite-from-gallery-image-path-in-andengine Please look at this.